# i can't display the list in a dialog with setMultiChoiceItems in Android

Tags: android, dialog

i have a method that returns the CharSequence[] and is not empty(checked with log) but is not displayed in the dialog.
do i have to initalize the boolean[] array;
i dont see any mistake so maybe there is something i miss.
my code is:

```
dbManager.open();
final CharSequence[] usrCats = dbManager.getUserCreatedCategories();

dbManager.close();
final boolean[] selections = new boolean[usrCats.length];

   alert = b.setTitle(R.string.remove_category)
            .setMessage(R.string.delete_categories_msg)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(usrCats, selections, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked){
            }
        })

            .setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            }       
    }).create();
  }
```

Comment: the dialog and the button is displayed but without the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why but `setMessage` and `setMultiChoiceItems` cannot work together. When I remove the `setMessage`, the list displays just fine.

Comment: Strange behavior indeed. Was debugging for hours with no luck. This worked like a charm- Thank you.

Comment: My Guess is if we pass setMessage it will think this dialog is not a list dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog _dialog;
 _dialog = new Dialog(classname.this);
            _dialog.setTitle("Title");
            _dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglist);
            ListView _output = (ListView) _dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.dialoglistid);
            _output.setAdapter(new exmpleadaptor());
            // _output.setOnItemClickListener(classname.this);
            //can use multichoice list option
            _dialog.show();
        }
```