# Can't add multi choice check box to dialog

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add a single check box to my dialog but I am not able to do it. It doesn't show up. Here is my code:

```
private void checkAnimationSettings() {

    try {
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        float animationDurationScale =
                Settings.Global.getFloat(cr, Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE);
        float windowsAnimationScale =
                Settings.Global.getFloat(cr, Settings.Global.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE);
        float transitionAnimationScale =
                Settings.Global.getFloat(cr, Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE);

        if (animationDurationScale == 0.0f
                || windowsAnimationScale == 0.0f
                || transitionAnimationScale == 0.0f) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean newerShowAnimationsOffWarning = sp.getBoolean("newerShowAnimationsOffWarning", false);

            if (newerShowAnimationsOffWarning) return;

            CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[]{"Bir daha gösterme"};
            Builder builder = new Builder(mainActivity);
            builder.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.animation_settings_warning_title_text));
            builder.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.animation_settings_warning_text));
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, this);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Tamam", null);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It because you are setting both message and items. try keeping any one of them or else use custom layout. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9127944/3831557

Comment: @RajenRaiysrela please add your comment as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127944/3831557)

> I don't know why but setMessage and setMultiChoiceItems cannot work
>   together. When I remove the setMessage, the list displays just fine.

setting both message and items list will not work.

For AlertDialog either you can keep message or item list.